# Facebook shares lost after switching to HTTPS

Tags: facebook, ssl, https

I recently installed an SSL certificate for **simplesharebuttons.com** and also decided to remove the www from the URL.

So from - `http://www.simplesharebuttons.com` - to - `https://simplesharebuttons.com`

The share counts are retrieved using a simple GET request from Facebook graph

Using PHP I replaced `https://` with `http://www.` to keep the share counts, which worked no problem, the share counts remained. However overnight (about a week after installing the SSL), share counts for simplesharebuttons.com have dropped from **3.1k to 3**!

Requests now for both old and new URLs are pulling back 3 shares.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Not if it could be solved with PHP programming or .htaccess changes? I mentioned replacing `https://` with `http://www.` which I have done using str_replace()

Answer (score 0):

The Open Graph Debugger shows a change in the canonical URL schema for `http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/`. I guess this might be the reason. Whether this is a bug or not I can't judge.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.simplesharebuttons.com

Comment: Hi Tobi, cheers for the answer. Not 100% sure what you mean, is there anything I can do here or do you believe that the potential bug would be on Facebook's side?

Comment: Baseline is: You changed a configuration on your webserver, and now shares are lost. I'm not sure whether this is legit from Facebook perspective or not. Maybe you might want to open a bug with them to be sure: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Thanks Tobi. I've reported it as a bug, hopefully they'll be able to sort it somehow!

Comment: @user3382680 could you let me know how this issue was solved?